# How can I stop Pycharm from raising type hint warnings about inherited classes using docstrings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct, pycharm, docstring

I am using Python 2.7 and writing docstrings, specifying types of fields and parameters using Sphinx notation.  In the following code from my project, two type hint errors are raised by Pycharm (explanation below):

```
from struct import Struct
import urllib


class OStruct(Struct):
    """ Abstract data structure for containing data to be transmitted over the network. """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        Struct.__init__(self, self.format)


class ConnectionIDStruct(OStruct):
    """ Sent from server to client via TCP on connect
        Sent from client to server via UDP to map UDP port to TCP connection object
        Direction: 2 way
    """
    type = 0x00
    format = '<B2Q'

    def __init__(self, upper, lower):
        """
        :type upper: int
        :type lower: int
        """
        OStruct.__init__(self)
        self.upper = upper
        self.lower = lower

    def pack(self):
        """ Pack the data.
        :rtype: str
        """
        return OStruct.pack(self, self.type, self.upper, self.lower)
```

OStruct is an abstract class subclassing the standard library class struct.Struct.  ConnectionIDStruct is one of many classes that will subclass OStruct.  In the code above there are two warnings generated both relating to type hinting and both expecting 'Struct' as the class:

> Expected type 'Struct', got 'OStruct' instead

on 'self' in this line:

```
Struct.__init__(self, self.format)
```

and

> Expected type 'Struct', got 'ConnectionIDStruct' instead

on 'self' in this line:

```
return OStruct.pack(self, self.type, self.upper, self.lower)
```

Docstrings using Sphinx notation seem to work in all other cases.

How can I prevent Pycharm from raising these warnings so that I don't have warnings being raised whenever I pass in a concrete OStruct subclass to a Struct method?

Comment: You seem to be using `struct.Struct` and `abc.ABCMeta` wrong. Despite the name, `struct.Struct` represents a data packer and unpacker, not a struct. The point of using it is to avoid having to repeatedly parse the format string. Your subclasses negate this advantage and represent a struct, rather than a packer/unpacker. Also, it's pointless to set `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` with no abstract methods. The resulting class [isn't even abstract](http://ideone.com/RjIucq)!

Comment: Note that when you inherit, you can use `super` rather than referring to the parent explicitly (e.g. `super(ConnectionIDStruct, self).__init__()`).